# Tool or technique to discover which JS/jQuery script is freezing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Which tool is used to discover what JS/jQuery is consuming too many resources or in infinite loop?**

More specifically I have an issue with this template: http://pages.revox.io/dashboard/latest/html/

Opening that page on Firefox 46.0.1 freezes the page after a few minutes. I'm unable to discover which JS/jQuery is causing this freeze with Firebug since it seems to be a script that is simply consuming too many resources and not in a plain freezing never ending loop (which would trigger the "Script XYZ is taking too long to execute" message)

Comment: I see memory usage steadily increasing in Firefox and not increasing in Chrome.  I would suggest making a list of things in the page that run by themselves (probably on a timer) and then start commenting them out one by one.  Run the page with task manager up so you can watch Firefox total memory consumption.  When you find that removing one of the dynamic elements causes memory consumption to stop increasing, then you will have found a culprit and you can examine that issue in more detail to find the cause.

Comment: 34 separate JS includes? The old-school technique for finding the problem would be to start with them all commented out, then add them back in one at a time until the problem occurs. (Or the reverse: comment them out one at a time until the problem stops.)

Comment: Since the nature of a page freezing is a script or block of code that uses up all of the resources, there's not much you can really do *after* it's happened. I'd suggest maybe trying to have a timer that will tell you if a script is taking too long, but defining what is "too long" is completely arbitrary. I highly suggest debugging your code, or at least try omitting potentially offending code and trying to work out by trial and error what your bug could be. EDIT: Why do you try to load so many files per page? Could be a contributing factor

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 46.0 for Ubuntu appears to have a pretty good debugger built into it.

Using the system monitor it's easy to see your page requires a fair amount of memory.
It's fairly easy to produce a call graph in Firefox if you go to Tools->Web Developer->Performance and record your page for a little while.
Once you've stopped the recording, just select the data in the menu on the left and Call-Tree on the top of the debug frame.
It presents a breakdown of which functions use the most processor time.

Looks to me like whatever the Gecko function is, it is just really expensive.

Also, the console points out some interesting things:

> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.v3.js:3:157
>
> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. html
>
> Empty string passed to getElementById().

Maybe addressing the issues pointed out by the console will help your freezing issue.

Comment: Id add that if its crashing in ff maybe check in chromes debugger there performance mapping tools are very good you may be able to see the evil piece of code there.